# How can one free memory used by heavy WPF Controls in a deterministic way?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, controls

I have been running into issues when Controls allocating big amounts of memory get destroyed and reconstructed using Input events from the UI.

Obviously, setting a Window's Content to null is not enough to free the memory the contained Control was using. It will be GCed eventually. But as Input events to destroy and construct Controls get more frequent, the GC seems to skip some objects.

I broke it down to this example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="window" MouseMove="window_MouseMove">
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private class HeavyObject : UserControl
        {
            private byte[] x = new byte[750000000];

            public HeavyObject()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i++ < 99999999; ) { } // just so we can follow visually in Process Explorer
                Content = "Peekaboo!"; // change Content to el cheapo re-trigger MouseMove
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Works 1:
            //while (true)
            //{
            //    window.Content = null;
            //    window.Content = new HeavyObject();
            //}
        }

        private void window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (window.Content == null)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                // Works 2:
                //new HeavyObject();
                //window.Content = "Peekaboo!"; // change Content to el cheapo re-trigger MouseMove
                //return;
                window.Content = new HeavyObject();
            }
            else
            {
                window.Content = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does allocate a ~750MB object (HeavyObject) at each MouseMove event and put it as the main Window's Content. If the Cursor is kept still on the Window the Content change will endlessly re-trigger the event.
The Reference to HeavyObject is nulled before its next construction and a futile attempt to GC its remains is triggered.

What we can see in ProcessExplorer / Taskman is, that there is sometimes 1.5GB or more allocated. If not, move the mouse wildly and leave and re-enter the window. If you compile for x86 without LARGEADDRESSAWARE, you'll get an OutOfMemoryException instead (limit ~1.3GB).

You won't encounter this behavior if you either allocate the HeavyObject in an endless loop without using mouse input (uncomment section "Works 1") or if you trigger the allocation by mouse input but do not put the object into the visual tree (uncomment seciton "Works 2").

So i suppose it has something to do with the visual tree lazily freeing resources. But then there is another strange effect: If 1.5GB are consumed during the cursor is outside the Window, it seems the GC won't kick in until MouseMove is triggered again. At least, memory consumption seems to stabilize as long as no further events are triggered. So either there is a long-living reference left somewhere or GC gets lazy when there is no activity.

Seems strange enough to me. Can you figure out what's going on?

**Edit:**
As BalamBalam commented: The data behind the Control could be dereferenced before destroying the Control. That would have been plan B. Nevertheless maybe there is a more generic solution.

Saying such Controls are bad code is not helpful. I would like to know why an object I hold no reference to gets GCed if I leave the UI alone for a few Ticks after dereferencing it, but lingers around forever if another one (that has to have been created by user input) immediately takes its place.

Comment: I can't figure out what your problem is... assuming the crazy code you have here is just for testing. But you have learned one thing: attempts to force GC often don't do what you think they will.

Comment: The code is an example, containing two workarounds where the problem won't occur. Just to limit presumptions. Problem is: Have big Control as Window Content -> Set new big Control as Window Content **by Mouse Input** -> More than one Big Control alive at once.

Comment: Well, I just hope no one would ever allocate a 750MB object on a mouse move. That's a very unrealistic scenario, and so your whole foundation here is shakey.

Comment: This is a drastic example. In my real application one opens and closes Controls by clicking Buttons. Those Controls display - and thus hold - data. The amount of memory needed is below 10MB per Control.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is not to allocate a heavy objec. I ahve prob lems coming up with a use case where this is not simpyl "bad pogrammer that should not program". Not sayoug you are - but without a business use case for this operation noone will provide you with a sensible answer.

Comment: I just think you are looking at this wrong.  The control itself is not heavy (in your example the control is not really a control) rather the data is heavy.  Separate the control from the data and bind to the data.  If you need to remove the control then clear the data and then destroy the control.  Why does a Window ever need 75,000,000 bytes?  A Window is for visual consumption - no live person is going to consume that much data.

Comment: The "drastic" nature of the example makes it worthless as a test case. You should not do that sort of thing. And if you have things being hidden/shown... that's not the same as created/destroyed. (that may be a hint for you)

Comment: Just imagine HeavyObject is an Image. A big one. It has to be loaded in code at runtime as a result of user interaction. The user might open and close images very fast. I managed to trigger the problem by just clicking Open- and Close-Buttons fast enough. Slow interaction seems to work fine. But I would not like to write that in the user manual.

Comment: My Application can hold several (near infinite) Image containing Controls at a time. I have to destruct them upon close or sometime later or else there would be multiple Controls just lying around, taking space. If I knew how to determine when "sometime later" is, the problem might be solved.

Comment: Can't you show a smaller image to the user, or maybe a compressed version? This way you could have two images, one small that is shown to the user and another very big that is stored on the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, I could reduce the amount of data. But that does not solve the problem. It will just buy some time. Problem is: my Model is at some time in a state where it has no refs to data at all. And yet if it allocates 1 more byte it might be out of memory.

Comment: -1 for I already answered the question once.  Infinite images should NOT equate to infinite controls.   Separate the control from data and bind to the data.   You could even use a ListView to host the image control with Virtualization andRecycling.

Comment: You should handle the images in chunks, not as a huge (mostly worthless and unseen) single item, if they are truly that large. 100mb images isn't a big deal, though. You need to work on your model... not trying to wrestle with the GC.

Comment: BalamBalam: I really tried to keep the example abstract. Infinite Controls are required by customer request. Each Image in a DockingWindow, if you must know. I really would like to focus on investigation of the supposed glitch in the VisualTree here and not on how to circumvent it.

Comment: @die_hoernse Shooting from the hip: The HeavyControl you mention hosts an image. Is the underlying image disposed when the control is nulled? Are you subscribing to any events on HeavyControl and not unsubscribing before nulling? Have you ran a profiler tool such as dotTrace memory over it to try to find out if this memory is managed, native, elligable for collection etc?

Comment: Andrew Barber: Yes, I could work on the model. But as I said to Komyg 2 Posts above yours: less data will only buy me time (or space). It does neither solve nor explain the phenomenon I described. The GC is only invoked directly in the example for demonstration purposes. I can always circumvent the memory leak. But I want to learn how it came to be.

Comment: @Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson: I Unsubscribed all events, disposed the ImageSource. Have not yet done the tracing as I thought to be missing just a rather trivial method call. Rather i have stripped down the Control in question to neither subscribe to events nor holding Image Data. The result is the - still glitching - simple example above. Thanks for being the most constructive comment so far.

Comment: It is not a glitch if the abstract sample is not realistic.  Infinite DockingWindows - really?  At 100 DockingWindows they would each be so small as to not be readable.   Yes GC does not do a good job destroying millions of or even thousands of Objects.  Hint, then don't use Objects that way.   Separate the object from the data and reuse objects - that is just responsible programming.  Virtualization was built for this - use it

Comment: @die_hoernse I think a more suitable question title would be "How to avoid overloading the .NET Garbage Collector when repeatedly reallocating large objects" and also state at the top the question code is mimicking a problem you are witnessing with loading images in a production app as opposed to "problem code" in itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think I might know whats going on here. Take it with a pinch of salt though ...

I modified your code slightly.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="window" MouseDown="window_MouseDown">
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private class HeavyObject : UserControl
        {
            private byte[] x = new byte[750000000];

            public HeavyObject()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 750000000; i++ )
                {                    
                    unchecked
                    {
                        x[i] = (byte)i;       
                    }
                }

                // Release optimisation will not compile the array
                // unless you initialize and use it. 
                Content = "Loadss a memory!! " + x[1] + x[1000]; 
            }
        }

        const string msg = " ... nulled the HeavyObject ...";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            window.Content = msg;
        }

        private void window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (window.Content.Equals(msg))
            {
                window.Content = new HeavyObject();
            }
            else
            {
                window.Content = msg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now run this up and click on the window. I modified the code to **not use GC.Collect()** and to **set the memory on mousedown**. I am compiling in **Release mode** and running **without a debugger** attached.

**Click slowly on the window**.

The first click you see the memory usage go up by 750MBytes. Subsequent clicks toggle the message between `.. Nulled the heavy object..` and `Loads a memory!` *so long as you click slowly.* There is a slight lag as the memory is allocated and deallocated. The memory usage shouldn't go over 750MBytes but it also doesn't decrease when the heavyobject is nulled. This is by-design as the [GC Large Object Heap is lazy and collects large object memory when new large object memory is needed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx). From MSDN:

> If I don't have enough free space to accommodate the large object allocation requests, I will first attempt to acquire more segments from the OS. If that fails, then I will trigger a generation 2 garbage collection in hope of freeing up some space.

**Click fast on the window**

Around 20 clicks. What happens? On my PC memory usage does not go up but the mainwindow now does not update the message any more. It freezes. I dont get an out of memory exception and the overall memory usage of my system stays flat.

**Stress the system using MouseMove on the Window**

Now replace the MouseDown for a MouseMove event (as per your question code) by changing this Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="window" MouseMove="window_MouseDown">
</Window>
```

I can move the mouse over it for quite a while but **eventually it throws an OutofMemoryException**. A good way to force the exception is do multiple moves then try to maximise the window.

**The Theory**

Ok so this is my theory. As your UI thread is running flat out creating and deleting memory inside a message loop event (MouseMove), the Garbage collector is unable to keep up. Garbage collection on the Large Object Heap is done [when memory is needed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx). It is also an expensive task so performed as infrequently as possible.

The lag we noticed when fast clicking on/off/on/off becomes far more pronounced when performed in a MouseMove. If another large object is to be allocated, according to that MSDN article the GC will either try to collect (if memory is not available) or will start using disk.

> System Is in Low Memory Situation: This happens when I receive the high memory notification from the OS. If I think doing a generation 2 GC will be productive, I will trigger one.

Now this part is interesting and I'm guessing here but

> Finally, as of right now, the LOH is not compacted as a part of collection, but that is an implementation detail that should not be relied on. So to make sure something is not moved by the GC, always pin it. Now take your newfound LOH knowledge and go take control of the heap.

So, if the Large Object Heap is not compacted, and you request multiple large objects in a tight loop, **is it possible that collections lead to fragmentation eventually causing an OutOfMemoryException even though there should theoretically be enough memory?**

**The solution**

Let's free up the UI thread a bit to allow the GC room to breathe. Wrap the allocation code in an asynchronous Dispatcher call and use a low priority, such as SystemIdle. This way it will *only* allocate the memory when the UI thread is free.

```
    private void window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
                if (window.Content.Equals(msg))
                {
                    window.Content = new HeavyObject();
                }
                else
                {
                    window.Content = msg;
                }
            }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
    }
```

Using this I can dance the mouse pointer all over the form **and it never throws an OutOfMemoryException**. Whether its really working or has "fixed" the problem I don't know but its worth testing.

**In conclusion**

- Note that objects of this size are going to be allocated on the Large Object Heap
- LOH allocations trigger a GC if not enough space is available
- The LOH is not compacted during a GC cycle so fragmentation may occur, leading to OutOfMemoryException despite there theoretically being enough memory
- Ideally re-use large objects and don't reallocate. If that is not possible:

  - Allcate your large objects in a background thread to decouple from the UI thread
  - To allow the GC room to breathe, use the Dispatcher to decouple the allocation until the application is idle

Comment: Thank you for this elaboration. I reproduced your tests. The "20 Clicks" = Freeze did not occur at my machine. the Window stayed unchanged until all Clicks were handled (took a while) and then returned to update normally. Maybe you did not wait long enough? Memory behavior is the same here. Maximizing the window under stress seems to do exactly the same as leaving and re-entering the window with the mouse cursor (as in the original question). Maybe the leave and enter events allocate memory so the next HeavyObject does not fit into the gap of the old one anymore?

Comment: @die_hoernse to force the software to keep it slow, you could use the Dispatcher with low priority to decouple the Click event from the DoBigMemoryOperation function and prevent re-entrancy until the BigMemoryOperation has returned. Doing your BigMemoryOperation in a background thread also allows reporting of progress and graying out the UI/disabling buttons while working - tricks like this can really help to prevent production crashes when stressing the GC

Comment: In "stress" mode, when there is twice (or more - made it 250 instead of 750MB) the memory of HeavyObject allocated and the cursor is outside the window, it stays allocated until the cursor re-enters. My theory is, GC is idle due to inactivity of the program and no system memory pressure. Given that there is no leak but the LOH will eventually be compacted I consider your last conclusion the solution: To keep it in a background thread. However, if I shall discover that memory stays allocated forever, even under memory pressure without mentionable I/O or CPU load, this question will be updated.

Comment: @die_hoernse you are correct, the large object heap will only run a garbage collect when new allocations occur.

Comment: big objects could of course be loaded in background. That requires implementation inside the corresponding control (or model - if one insists on MVVM). I wanted to keep the UI framework dumb and just let it open (create) and close (destroy) controls of any kind. It would be nice if the UI could easily defend itself against memory glitches due to synchronous toggled big controls. Ok, so it is careful loading in every control. And pray 3rd parties also do it :)

Comment: @die_hoernse such safeguards / preventions would also occur in a C++ app - in fact, more so. The GC is fairly solid, just need to design your code a bit to gently push it in the right direction